# How to replace all from string except of part which follow regex pattern?

Tags: regex, string, kotlin, replace

I have pattern `\+\d.AT` and some string like "test 123 +1 AT test end". And i need to remove all except part which follow regex pattern. How i can do that? For now my code remove part which follow pattern if in string have some part which follow pattern.

```
val comment = "test 123 +1 AT test end" 
if("\\+\\d.AT".toRegex().containsMatchIn(comment)) {
    val regexpString = comment.replace("\\+\\d.AT".toRegex(), "")
    print(regexpString)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Match the entire string by putting `.*` before and after the pattern, and put a capture group around the part you want to keep. Then use a back-reference in the replacement to copy that to the result.

```
val regexpString = comment.replace(".*(\\+\\d.AT).*".toRegex(), "$1")
```

Comment: @Omnikross Do you mean you want to get `+1 AT`? Why replace then? Use `find()`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Yes, but example that i provided is a short version of my code. I have a list of patterns like this and in comment i can have a lot of parts which follow pattern